# Meteor - How can I detect if an app has been opened?

Tags: ios, meteor, startup

I'm running a Meteor app on IOS and I'd like to reset the badge number to 0 when the app is opened.  My logic is to set the badge to zero whenever the app is opened, and increment it until it is opened again.  How can I see if an app was pressed/opened?  `Meteor.startup` doesn't seem to work.  Is there some method called when the app is opened?

https://github.com/raix/push

Comment: put your method in app willBecomeActive in appdelegate

Comment: @TejasArdeshna I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // set badge to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a script in a template onCreated section, e.g.

```
Template.example.onCreated(function(){
    //run your function here
});
```

Or put it in a template helper if you rely on reactive data.

Answer (score 0):

This seems late, but for future reference:
You don't need to increment/decrement badge count manually.
Just add the properties `badge` and `clearBadge` in your **client side** Push Configuration on `Meteor.startup` like this:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Push.Configure({
      ios: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
        clearBadge: true
      }
    })
});
```

This will increment your badgeCount as soon as a notification arrives and will set the count to 0 when the user opens the app.

For more detailed info, please follow this
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md